# How to plot top5 features_importances using RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, random-forest

I am trying to plot the feature_importance of a RandomForestRegressor model. However, I have 307 features (after OneHotEncoding) in my dataset, so plotting all of them is not really helpful aesthetically.

How could I plot just the top5 (or top10) ones?

Here is my actual code:

```
# Help function to plot feature_importances 
def plot_feature_importances(model_to_plot, features_list, x_train_set):
    # Wichtigkeit der eizelnen Features plotten! 

    plt_x = np.linspace(0,len(features_list)-1,len(features_list))

    print("Features sorted by their score:")

    font = {'family' : 'normal',
            'weight' : 'normal',
            'size'   : 12}

    plt.rc('font', **font)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))

    plt.bar(plt_x, model_to_plot.feature_importances_, width=0.5, color="blue",align='center')
    plt.gca().set_xticklabels(plt_x, rotation=60 )
    plt.title('Features importance in decision making', position=(.5,1.05), fontsize=20)
    plt.xticks(plt_x, features_list, fontsize=12)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Relative Information %', fontsize=15)
    plt.xlabel('Features', fontsize=15)
    plt.show()

    print("Feature ranking:")

    importances = model_to_plot.feature_importances_
    std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in model_to_plot.estimators_],
                 axis=0)
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

    for f in range(x_train.shape[1]):
        print("%d. Feature %s (%.2f)" % (f + 1, x_train_set.columns[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]]))
```

and plotting using the following code gives me something like this:

```
plot_feature_importances(model, features, x_train)
```

[image: plot feature importances]

Comment: Compute features importance, put them in an array if not already, `argsort` the array, and plot?

Answer (score 0):

You failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I cannot provide a final working answer. Nevertheless, you can try the following modified code. I have removed the lines for setting x-ticks. But that part is trivial

```
def plot_feature_importances(model_to_plot, features_list, x_train_set):
    to_plot = 5 # <---- Define the number to plot
    importances = model_to_plot.feature_importances_
    std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in model_to_plot.estimators_],
                 axis=0)
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1][0:to_plot] # <--- Take the top 5 

    font = {'family' : 'normal',
            'weight' : 'normal',
            'size'   : 12}

    plt.rc('font', **font)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))

    plt.bar(range(to_plot), importances[indices], width=0.5, color="blue",align='center') # <--- Plot the top 5 
    plt.xticks(range(to_plot), features_list[indices], fontsize=12) # <--- add ticks
    plt.title('Features importance in decision making', position=(.5,1.05), fontsize=20)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Relative Information %', fontsize=15)
    plt.xlabel('Features', fontsize=15)
    plt.show()

    for f in range(x_train.shape[1]):
        print("%d. Feature %s (%.2f)" % (f + 1, x_train_set.columns[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]]))

plot_feature_importances(model, features, x_train)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not plotting the x-ticks (there is just numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5) and this is not printing the exact value under the plot as I am doing with my actual function (code above) using for f in range(x_train.shape[1]):

Comment: @ZelelB: Yes, I removed the print command as it had nothing to do with the plotting. The main question is: Is it plotting the top 5 features?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed. And thank you anyway for answering. But I am now trying to get these back in the function and somehow getting crazy with errors, and not solving this problem :-/ Could you please just modify the small portion of code, so that it works with that? It would really help! Thanks so much anyway

Comment: @ZelelB: I added one line `plt.xticks(...)`. Check it now

Comment: waiting for a model training since a couple of minutes to execute the change. Thanks for asking! But your solution does not print the sorted importances under the plot, with the exact value, as mine does. Right? How to do that so that it prints the feature importance in % like mine?

Comment: No, I get this error: ---> 16     plt.xticks(range(to_plot), features_list[indices], fontsize=12) # <--- add ticks

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @ZelelB : First `print (features_list[indices])` and see if you get 5 values in a list. What does it print? Also you can try `list(range(to_plot))` although I doubt that this is the problem

Comment: @ZelelB : This is why I try not to answer questions which lack [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the above comment doesn't help, then unless you provide a MCVE which I can simply copy paste and run in my editor to get the above figure, I can't help. It takes unnecessarily the whole day in chasing the unknown.

Comment: when I try to print features_list[indices] I get the same error as above at the print line. I tried to print list(range(to_plot)) and 5 values get printed [0,1,2,3,4]. So I changed features_list[indices] to list(range(to_plot)), and now it plots the bar diagram, but the ticks are 0,1,2,3,4 and then under the graph the 5 features are printed, but at the end this error: ---> 24         print("%d. Feature %s (%.2f)" % (f + 1, x_train_set.columns[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]]))

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Comment: Any help here please? I just want to have the x-ticks printed with the feature names and this exception at the end of the print of the features away. The solution of @Sheldore works. Just these small 2 problems cited above in my last comment..